# sort a list using a dictionary

Tags: python, sorting

I have a following list with data:

```
[['0', 'r1', 0.02, '-115.047611580259'], ['-', 'r1', 0.02, '-115.047523465090'], ['+', 'r1', 0.02, '-115.047530021958'], ['-', 'r2', 0.02, '-115.047482517212'], ['+', 'r2', 0.02, '-115.047488665041'], ['-', 'r3', 0.02, '-115.047537136035'], ['+', 'r3', 0.02, '-115.047540343182'], ['-', 'r4', 0.02, '-115.047536709065'], ['+', 'r4', 0.02, '-115.047539744629'], ['-', 'r5', 0.02, '-115.047536709065'], ['+', 'r5', 0.02, '-115.047539744630'], ['-', 'T1', 0.017453292519943295, '-115.047582049644'], ['+', 'T1', 0.017453292519943295, '-115.047580299567'], ['-', 'T2', 0.017453292519943295, '-115.047565855131'], ['+', 'T2', 0.017453292519943295, '-115.047566778954'], ['-', 'T3', 0.017453292519943295, '-115.047566430596'], ['+', 'T3', 0.017453292519943295, '-115.047566580788'], ['-', 'T4', 0.017453292519943295, '-115.047566430596'], ['+', 'T4', 0.017453292519943295, '-115.047566580788'], ['-', 'T5', 0.017453292519943295, '-115.047582679863'], ['+', 'T5', 0.017453292519943295, '-115.047582679863'], ['-', 'T6', 0.017453292519943295, '-115.047581038699'], ['+', 'T6', 0.017453292519943295, '-115.047580181415'], ['-', 'T7', 0.017453292519943295, '-115.047580181415'], ['+', 'T7', 0.017453292519943295, '-115.047581038699'], ['t', 'tes', 0.017453292519943295, '-115.047611580259']]
```

I am trying to sort values, so I created dictionary:

```
index_sort = {'r1':1, 'r2':2, 'T1':3, 'r3':4, 'T2':5, 'T3':6, 'r4':7, 'T4':8, 'T5':9, 'r5':10, 'T6':11, 'T7':12}
Eall_sorted = sorted(Eall, key = lambda e: index_sort[e[1]])
```

The problem is that I am getting the error in return:

```
Eall_sorted = sorted(Eall, key = lambda e: index_sort[e[1]])
KeyError: 'tes'
```

Could anybody elaborate what is going wrong on with my code?

Comment: You left `tes` out of `index_sort`.

Comment: It totally makes sense. I haven't noticed it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to map `tes` in the dictionary, add `'tes':13` to the index_sort and it works!

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
index_sort = {'r1':1, 'r2':2, 'T1':3, 'r3':4, 'T2':5, 'T3':6, 'r4':7, 'T4':8, 'T5':9, 'r5':10, 'T6':11, 'T7':12}
```

you forgot to add 'tes'.

You can replace it with

```
index_sort = {'r1':1, 'r2':2, 'T1':3, 'r3':4, 'T2':5, 'T3':6, 'r4':7, 'T4':8, 'T5':9, 'r5':10, 'T6':11, 'T7':12, 'tes':13}
```